WebApplicationFactory get server scope
I'm writing integration tests but I'm currently stuck... one of scoped services requires an extra initialization step to set up a private field, but when I try to call this extra step in my test code, it is not working as expected.
Imagine this 3rd party service (this code I cannot change):
interface IScopedService 
{
    bool IsFooValid(int foo);
}

class ScopedService 
{
   private List<int> _Foo = new();

   public void Register(int foo)
   {
      _Foo.Add(foo);
   }

   public bool IsFooValid(int foo)
   {
      return _Foo.Contains(foo);
   }
}

This service is used by my controller:
class MyController(IScopedService scopedServiceInController) : ApiController 
{
   [HttpPost]
   public bool MyFunc(int foo)
   {
       return scopedServiceInController.IsFooValid(foo);
   }
}

The controller method is called from the client via:
class MyEndpoints(HttpClient httpClient) 
{
    public bool MyFunc(int foo)
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"path") 
            {
                Content = JsonContent.Create(foo)
            };

        var result = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

        if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode) 
        {
            return null;
        }

        return await result.Content.ReadFromJson<bool>();
    }
}

This is the integration test for that method:
class MyWebApplicationFactory: WebApplicationFactory<Program>, IAsyncLifetime 
{
    public  IServiceProvider ScopedServiceProvider => _Scope.ServiceProvider;
    private IServiceScope _Scope;

    public virtual async Task InitializeAsync() 
    {
        _Scope = Services.CreateScope();
    }

    public new virtual async Task DisposeAsync() 
    {
        _Scope.Dispose();
    }
}

class MyServiceTests: IClassFixture<MyWebApplicationFactory> 
{
    private readonly MyWebApplicationFactory _Factory;
    private readonly MyEndpoints _Sut;

    public MyServiceTests(MyWebApplicationFactory factory)
    {
         _Factory = factory;

         var client = factory.CreateClient();
         _Sut = new MyEndpoints(client);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        // Arrange
        var scopedServiceInTest = _Factory.ScopedServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ScopedService>();
        scopedServiceInTest.Register(1);

        // Act
        var actual = _Sut.MyFunc(1);

        // Assert
        actual.Should.BeTrue();      
    }
}

My trouble is that scopedServiceInController is not the same instance as scopedServiceInTest => foo list is not initialized => test will fail.
My theory is that I should not create new scope in MyWebApplicationFactory, but get instance of scope that server uses to resolve scopedServiceInController ...
Any idea how to fix this?
PS: in my code ScopedService is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager<User> and I need to call RegisterTokenProvider method if that helps ...

Edit: As requested this is how im registering services:
public static void Register(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration) {
    services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(
                o => {
                   // identity configuration, not relevant
                }
            )
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyIdentityDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
            .AddUserManager<MyUserManager>()
            .AddRoleManager<MyRoleManager>();            
        services.AddControllers();

        services.AddScoped<IRoleManager>(o => o.GetRequiredService<MyRoleManager>());
        services.AddScoped<IUserManager>(o => o.GetRequiredService<MyUserManager>());
}

class MyIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, string>;
class MyUserManager: UserManager<User>, IUserManager;
class MyRoleManager: RoleManager<Role>, IRoleManager;

and controller that uses service:
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public sealed class UserController(IUserManager userManager) : ControllerBase {
}


Scoped services will be instantiated per scope (request), so in your MyFunc you're calling API then it will get a new instance from DI. also share how you register service into DI.
